# get query string value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following string/query string:

```
ajax/hovercard/hovercard.php?id=100000472545907&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22stream%22%7D
```

What is the best way to extract the id?

Comment: Is that id always a number?

Comment: Any question that says "What is the *best* way..." to do something usually means it will be a subjective (not objective) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
yoururl.match(/id=(.*)&/)[1]
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppZZv/)

Comment: hehe, you also were downvoted by some morons )

Comment: This just makes so many assumptions. The URL needs to be parsed properly.

Comment: @naomik: we are developers, we solve the tasks as they appear. The theoretics may theoretize for years, while we just provide a solutions for the business.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought SO was about helping educate people more than just giving them some one-off snippet that works in a narrow solution space.

Comment: @naomik: treat it as a way to teach a person about how to ask better question. Well, I see your point, thank you for being such pedantic. Give me a second to check your answer. See you there. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245542/251311 --- here is the first. Should I continue?

Comment: @PSL: **NO**. Please implement the proper lexer for the URI grammatics and parser for it. Only that answer will be acceptable. It's such a shame to provide one liners for 18k rep guy!

Comment: This won't match if the id is the only URL parameter, correct?

Comment: If the query string parameter being searched for doesn't end with an `&` I.E. it's the last parameter then this code will break. It's unreliable. I will upvote if it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
params = location.search.substring(location.search.indexOf('id')).split('&')[0]

  id = params.substr(3)
```

Comment: the question asked for the query params, right? what is wrong

Comment: This looks like the best answer here.

Comment: Note that this should be wrapped up into a function so that inside you can count the length of the key and dynamically populate that `substr` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always shipped in this exact order - then

```
url.match(/\d+/)
```

otherwise

```
url.match(/id=(\d+)/)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @naomik: I'm following the task description. If it's not complete - it's not my problem.

Comment: @naomik: please prove it's not the best? Please keep in mind that your criterias to determine the solution quality may not match mine.

Comment: @naomik: you're making assumptions that such key may appear in the url. I'm used to using APIs that don't change randomly. Stop making assumptions please. If you want to prove my solution won't work - please ask OP to provide the URL my regex won't match

Comment: The second line of code is wrong, you are missing a `[1]`.

Comment: @Alex W: it's intentionally - that's a homework for the OP. The same for the first one